# document.location / parent.location - Can they be blocked?

Tags: javascript

I am using the above 2 commands on my website. It seems they work for 95% of people visiting the page it should trigger but for others it doesn't.

Does anyone know if these javascript commands can be blocked at all? I am having a real headache finding out why they don't work sometimes.

p.s I am not using these for spam or anything, just for processing payments.

Thanks.

EDIT: I have a  tag replacement for JS being disabled. I am thinking more of a random blocking that a user isn't generally aware of. None of the people who have reported the issue would be likely to install a pop up blocker

Comment: There is no *location* property of the [HTMLDocument interface](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-26809268), perhaps you are confusing it with [window.location](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/history.html#dom-location). What "commands" are you using? What is it that "works for 95% of people"?

Comment: In terms of this not working, make sure the 5% aren't all using the same browser, if they are, you can link it to specific browser behaviour.

Comment: The information I get back is VERY vague. Most of the people using the site are non technical and when you ask what browser, they say windows ...

Comment: @RobG - Well it works normally ... Why would that happen?

Comment: Yes some anti virus softwares might block JavaScript as "additonal security" so ask those clients what kind of Anti Virus they have installed or protection programs.

Comment: @Shadow - Do you have any idea which ones would be likely to? I need to try and test all theories.

Comment: @Shadow - Just to add, all other javascript works fine. It just seem these parts are breaking.

Comment: I know that Norton Internet Security for example is injecting its own JavaScript to every page.. dunno if it also block anything but it might affect. AVG has feature that will block links to certain websites, so they also interfere with the "raw" contents of web pages. But sorry, can't find any specific AV doing what you describe.

Comment: As a side note, you can add small AJAX code called with a timer that will log message like "redirection failed" with browser details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `window.location` instead of `document.location` for full support across all browsers.

Are you using iframes? That's the only reason you should use `window.parent` or else `window.parent` just points to the current window.

If you're running this code inside of an iframe to change the parent windows locations (`window.parent.location`) - it will only work on the same domain. If the domains are different your code will fail.

There are work arounds to getting subdomain support working using `document.domain` but I'm already making too many assumptions in what your issue is.

Comment: window.location change made. I am using JQuery Colorbox and the code "should" be on the same domain. If the code was going to fail because of something generic like cross domain, I would expect it to break everytime ...

Comment: Okay, see if you can still get the issue to occur with the change.

Comment: Well the part of the code that was using docoument.location has been disabled (its an uneccessary step while debugging) and this issue still occurs with parent.location. DO I need `window.parent.location` instead of `parent.location`? Does it matter?

Comment: You only need parent.location if your page is inside an iframe and you want to change the parent window's URL.

Answer (score 0):

Anything on the client side can be blocked. Two examples:

1. Simply disable javascript in your browser
2. Use a plugin which disables certain Javascript actions (something like TamperData for Firefox)

Comment: Well I have a <noscript> tag replacement for JS being disabled. But I am thinking more of a random blocking that a user isn't generally aware of. None of the people who have reported the issue would be likely to install a pop up blocker.

Comment: try just using `location.href`

Answer (score 0):

As RobG said in a comment, document.location is not part of a standard, though implemented in some browsers.  I think you should be using window.location.  See the notes in [this mozilla reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.location) on document.location that say document.location used to be a read-only property and is non-standard and window.location is recommended instead.

parent.location can be blocked by same-origin security settings if you're framed and the parent frame is not the same origin as your frame.

Comment: I have made the change to window.location and it still works for me so I will leave it like that. ANy idea how I can enable some same origin security settings (in any browser) so I can test this? I am using all this in conjunction with JQuery ColorBox so not sure if that falls in line with your comments.

Comment: @webnoob - are you using frames or iframes?  What are you trying to accomplish with parent.location?  Can you include sample code?  Is the domain of the parent window, the same as the domain of your window?  FYI, parent.location should be the same as window.parent.location.